# CodeIgniter, multiple queries in same model method or multiple calls to model in controller?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, model, codeigniter-2

I'm just starting to convert some basic applications to CodeIgniter and I'm trying to make sure that I start off on the right footing.

Most actions in my controller require at least 1 query and as I see it there are 2 ways to go about this:

1. Combine the queries into a single method in the model, therefore making only a single call to the model from the controller.
2. Have each query be its own method in the model, then call each method in turn from the controller.

So far I've adopted my own policy, but I'm not sure if it's advised or breaking the MVC pattern.

If the queries are directly related to one another and only ever run together in sequence (the 2nd query is dependent on the 1st running successful), **or** data from the 1st query is passed to a 2nd query and it's the 2nd query that returns the actual display result set, then I go with **#1**

If each of the queries is returning its own individual result set for display, then I go with **#2**.

Is there a recommended way to structure and separate the logic in this scenario?
The last thing I want to do is cause myself a nightmare later down the line. My gut instinct is telling me that as much of the logic should be in the controller as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking is right in that if a certain set of queries will only ever be run together, they should belong to the same method in the model. Free-standing queries should be in methods of their own, this way you can call them from the controller when required.

To combine multiple queries, you can either make multiple calls from the controller like this:

```
$this->your_model->doQuery1();
$this->your_model->doQuery2();
$this->your_model->doQuery3();
```

Or (and this is what I would do), create a wrapper method in the model that runs those three queries.

So you can do

```
$this->your_model->runQueries();
```

where

```
function runQueries() {
  $this->doQuery1();
  $this->doQuery2();
  $this->doQuery3(); 
}
```

This makes it more malleable to later change.

Finally, as for your statement 'as much of the logic should be in the controller as possible', this actually goes against the school of though of `skinny controller, fat model` that some people subscribe to. As any other school of thought, it is not set in stone.

Comment: Skinny controller, fat model makes sense. Otherwise your controller could branch out of control quickly. Also I like your suggestion about combining queries into a wrapper method. Presumably I would put the logic, "if Q1 returned no results then FALSE, otherwise doQuery2()" in that wrapper method?

Comment: Damn missed the edit deadline ^^^. Because I could also test for FALSE else $this->your_model_doQuery2() in my controller quite easily.

Comment: I would recommend doing the check in the wrapper method in the model (if query1 does not return false, run query2 and return the results). This encapsulates the entire logic in that method, so you don't need to worry about it in the controller(s). You can just call the method as and when you need.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: slapping on a framework on exiting application - always a bad choice. Frameworks do not make you application better. They are there to make development faster.

Also, you have to understand that CodeIgniter is not really implementing proper MVC. Instead it is mimicking Rails architecture and naming conventions. It's actually closer to [MVP](http://www.wildcrest.com/Potel/Portfolio/mvp.pdf) pattern.

---

In any case, **controllers must be as light as possible**.

If implementing proper MVC or MVC-inspired pattern, all of the domain business logic would be in thee model layer and all of presentation logic in the views. Controller would be only passing relevant data to model layer and current view.

When writing code for CodeIgniter, you should keep as much domain logic as possible in the "models" and most of the presentation logic in the [view helpers](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html).

What in CodeIgniter are called "models" are mostly [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject), which sometimes are merged with storage logic (violating [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)) to implement [active record](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) pattern.

The best option for you would be to create *higher level* "models" which would act as [services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_%28systems_architecture%29) and would separate the controllers from direct interaction with CodeIgniter's "models".

In your described situation, where you have to make two requests to different "models", this operation would be done is the such services. And the service aggregate the data from both "models" and pass it to the controller.

---

For example: if you are registering new user, you would have to perform two operations - create an entry for the account in storage (usually - database) and sent user notification to email. Those both operations can be contained in the service, that is responsible for user management.

Controller would only ask the service to crate new account. Fact that service would perform multiple operations( initialize a `User` "model", assign data to it, store it and then on success, initiate `Mailer` and send an email) is completely irrelevant to the controller. Controller would only want to know the list of errors (if the list was empty, everything was ok).

.. *my two cents*.